# Xampp field name changing

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

How can I change my table entries name in **XAMPP**? My table name is '*products*', the fields are *name*, *item*, *price*. Now, If i want to change the name of field '*item*' to '*id*'. So how can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you rename your table column name:

SQL:

```
EXEC SP_RENAME 'products.item', 'id', 'COLUMN'
```

MySQL(Please change data type to correct one):

```
ALTER TABLE products CHANGE item id INT
```

Hope this helps